# Access denied for created file

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

My script creates an image and saves it on the server. Afterwards it changes its file permissions to 644, so other users can read the image:

```
imagejpeg($myImage, $savePath);
chmod($savePath, 0644);
```

References to the image will be wrapped with another script that allows me to add caching headers. Essentially, this second script adds some headers and then writes the file's content to the output stream:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
//... caching headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
header("Content-Length: $Size");
readfile($ImageFile);
```

However, this results in a permission failure:

```
Warning:  readfile(...) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /.../showImage.php on line 20
```

Line 20 is the line containing the `readfile()` call.

A call to `fileperms($ImageFile)` returns 33412, which is 101204 in octal. Via ftp I can verify that the actual file permissions (for the ftp user) are 644.

The `fileowner()` of the image is a user with a 4-digit username, while the `get_current_user()` of the script is my ftp account.

I can access the image directly via the browser. Only the script cannot access it.

How can I enable script access for the file?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but have you tried setting it to 0755. It might be possible, that PHP needs execute rights to open the file. If changing the chmod solves your problem, you can work on the permission situation of your Apache, FTP, ... users

Comment: Yes, 755 doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the filename in $ImageFile is what you intend for it to be?

Comment: @David: Yes, of course. Otherwise calls to `fileperms()` and `fileowner()`wouldn't work as well.

Comment: They would if $ImageFile was the name of a different file. That's what I was suggesting.